# how to create custom indicators for small task like window spread?

Tags: indicator, panel

I really like `window spread` functionality in Ubuntu.

is there any way to get it in top-panel like an indicator, for faster access?
Better if I can get it next to menu icon in panel corner.

Thanks in advanced! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use Ubuntu's indicator feature.**

This is a python example that will perform the function you described.  When you run the script, you'll have the clickable indication in the navigation bar.

Save this as `myindicator.py`.  Make it executable and run it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# This code is an example for a tutorial on Ubuntu Unity/Gnome AppIndicators:
# http://candidtim.github.io/appindicator/2014/09/13/ubuntu-appindicator-step-by-step.html
# https://gist.github.com/candidtim/7290a1ad6e465d680b68

import os
import signal
import json
import subprocess

from urllib2 import Request, urlopen # URLError

from gi.repository import Gtk as gtk
from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as appindicator
from gi.repository import Notify as notify



APPINDICATOR_ID = 'myappindicator'

def main():
    indicator = appindicator.Indicator.new(APPINDICATOR_ID, os.path.abspath('sample_icon.svg'), appindicator.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)
    indicator.set_status(appindicator.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    indicator.set_menu(build_menu())
    notify.init(APPINDICATOR_ID)
    gtk.main()

def build_menu():
    menu = gtk.Menu()

    item_windowsspread = gtk.MenuItem('Windows Spread')
    item_windowsspread.connect('activate', windowsspread)
    menu.append(item_windowsspread)

    item_quit1 = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    item_quit1.connect('activate', quit1)
    menu.append(item_quit1)

    menu.show_all()
    return menu

def fetch_joke():
    request = Request('http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random?limitTo=[nerdy]')
    response = urlopen(request)
    joke = json.loads(response.read())['value']['joke']
    return joke

def windowsspread(_):
    subprocess.call("xdotool key super+w", shell=True)
    return windowsspread

def quit1(_):
    notify.uninit()
    gtk.main_quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
    main()
```

Details for making indicator in Ubuntu can be found at:
[Ubuntu ApplicationIndicators wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DesktopExperienceTeam/ApplicationIndicators)